# Pycharm auto-import is not working with variables inside f-strings

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

It seems like the auto import functionality of Pycharm doesn't work on f-strings. Does anybody has experienced the same behaviour ? Does a solution exist to fix this ?

What I mean is this: Let's say we have a constant in a `moduleA`, and that in `moduleB`, we do something like:

```py
print(f"{A_CONSTANT_IN_MODULEA}")
```

I would expect Pycharm to prompt for auto-importing `A_CONSTANT_IN_MODULEA`, but it doesn't.

I am using Pycharm Community edition version 2019.2 on OpenSUSE

Comment: I'm not sure what's different about my PyCharm, but I've never once been prompted to auto-import a module. Is that a plugin?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think it's built into pycharm. Maybe it's deactivated on yours. Go to Settings->Editor->General->Auto Import and check "Show import popup" under Python section to activate it

Comment: Sweet, ya it was off for some reason. I'll play around with it for a bit now. Thanks.

Comment: Ya, I can reproduce. I suspect thought that this is just an oversight by Jetbrains. Maybe send them a ticket?

Comment: Yeah, will try that. Maybe it's not straight forward to implement...

Comment: For anyone interested in this, here is a link to the bug ticket so that you can follow on any advance: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38966